How can you build a URI in Java that has a path segment fully URL encoded?
I'm trying to call the GitLab Repository File API (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html)
It states that the file path is part of the URL path and it should be url encoded.
When i try to use RestTemplate.getForObject and pass in the built url as a string it re-encodes the encoded path segment...
final var uri = "projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb?ref=main";
return restTemplate.getForObject(uri, RepositoryFileResponse.class);

This calls projects/13083/repository/files/app%252Dmodels%252Dkey%252Erb?ref=main aka double encoded..

Ok then i try to build a URI and pass that in instead of the String.
final var uri = getUrl("13083", "main", "app/models/key.rb");

return restTemplate.getForObject(uri, RepositoryFileResponse.class);

private URI getUri(final Integer projectId, final String branch, String filePath) {
        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("projects/{projectId}/repository/files")
                .pathSegment("{encodedFilePath}")
                .queryParam("ref", "{branch}")
                .buildAndExpand(projectId, encodedFilePath, branch)
                .encode()
                .toUri();
}

This approach builds the URI projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey.rb?ref=main AND the RestTemplate.getForObject does not re-encode it!
However that . in the URI is still not encoded...

Not even sure why i tried this one but ofc it doesn't work..
private URI getUri(final Integer projectId, final String branch, String filePath) {
        final var encodedFilePath = filePath.replaceAll("\\.", "%2E");
        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("projects/{projectId}/repository/files")
                .pathSegment("{encodedFilePath}")
                .queryParam("ref", "{branch}")
                .buildAndExpand(projectId, encodedFilePath, branch)
                .encode()
                .toUri();
}

This results in a URI projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%252Erb?ref=main
A double encoded . character!!!

To be clear the desired URI is projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb?ref=main

Decode the path first using a library such as Spring's UriUtils.decode

The dot has no special meaning in a URI. It should not matter whether it is encoded as %2E or just left as-is. In other words, your first approach should be sufficient.
